Caddy subdomain issue, `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`
First time using Caddy. I have a VPS (Hetzner if that's relevant) running Docker containers to host my projects on. So far there is only one API hosted there, and Caddy to handle HTTPS and act as a reverse proxy to filter traffic between projects via subdomains.
Before adding Caddy, the backend worked fine using uvicorn for FastAPI.
I can't get the Caddy config working correctly. I've tried just about every combination of things I can think of. With the current Caddyfile below, blocks 1-4 work correctly. Block 5, even with just the respond string, doesn't.
# 1. This block only works for HTTP requests, not HTTPS as Caddy doesn't provide SSL certs for IP addresses. Not a problem. 
server_ip {
    redir https://www.mydomain.win 301
}

# 2. Redirect all to www.
mydomain.win {
    redir https://www.mydomain.win 301
}

# 3. Redirect all subdomain requests to www.
*.mydomain.win {
    redir https://www.{host}{uri} 301
}

# 4. This block is so I can see how the server has responded to the request
www.mydomain.win {
    @http {
        protocol http
    }
    @https {
        protocol https
    }

    respond @http "Responded by HTTP" 200
    respond @https "Responded by HTTPS" 200
}

# 5. This should ultimately be acting as a reverse proxy, fow now I just want to get it to respond with the below message.
www.subdomain.mydomain.win {
    respond "Requested subdomain" 200
#    reverse_proxy localhost:8000
}

I mostly get ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH. I can see in the certificates folder it has generated a certificate for the subdomain that I'm trying to access. I'm using an up to date browser and I haven't specified ciphers, as I think Caddy should be doing this automatically?
When I compare this file to other examples it already seems significantly more complicated. I've tried specifying the certificate path locations, and different combinations of ciphers, but no change.
Is there somewhere obvious that I'm going wrong?

It seems to be related to Cloudflare's proxy - turning this off while keeping the SSL mode to strict lets the connection work. Toggling the proxy takes a little while to come into force, so you have to deactivate it and then wait a while. I don't know why this is happening, just that disabling the proxy solved the issue.
